# How to use forward slashes in mod_rewrite as separator

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my basic folder structure:

```
root    
-->inhalt.php
-->imgs/img.gif
-->css/global.css
```

Here my url to be rewirtten:

```
http://www.example.com/dev/project/sub/unterkunfte/wagram
```

And here my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/project/
RewriteRule ^sub/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ inhalt.php?id=$1&k=$2 [NC,L]
```

The rule rewrites the URL correctly, however my imgs and css are no longer visible.
How do I get the forward slash in my RewriteRule to act as a simple separator without effecting the connection to my imgs and css?